# Installed Memory (RAM): 8GB (4GB Useable)

Tags: windows-7, memory, 64-bit

I have 4X 2GB RAM sticks installed, Windows 7 Ultimate x64 shows "Installed Memory (RAM): 8GB (4GB Useable)" in the system information. The motherboard says it supports up to 16GB of memory. I had Windows XP x64 and I'm pretty sure it was able to use all 8Gigs of memory. I've just formatted and am not burning through 4GB for sure.

*The BIOS only show 4096MB while booting.
I was only able to find one option relating to memory mapping and it took it from 4Gigs to 3 and change.
CPU-Z shows all 4 sticks as 2048MB
I went in to msconfig and checked the limits, they are not set.
I tried resetting the CPU and RAM sticks 3 times, the CPU has no pins to be bent (flat contacts, I5)
I rearranged all the RAM.
I have separate video memory from the system memory.
I have a 64 bit OS (I am 100% certain)

Hardware:

[Memory: Four Corsair XMS3 TW3X4G1333C9AG](http://www.tigerdirect.ca/applications/SearchTools/item-details.asp?EdpNo=4837614)


[Motherboard: Asus P7P55D Pro](http://www.tigerdirect.ca/applications/SearchTools/item-details.asp?EdpNo=5570286)

CPU: Intel Core i5-760 BX80605I5760
Graphics: Two ZOTAC ZT-50401-10L GeForce GTX 550 Ti

If anyone has new ideas or knows the exact setting in the bios, it would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: It appears that the motherboard thinks it's running in 32-bit mode. I have no idea why this is happening, though.

Comment: It's been a while, but did you find a solution?

Answer (score 6):

Make sure the `Memory Remapping` BIOS setting in the *Advanced* tab is enabled:

[image]

Comment: Where?​​​​​​​​​

Comment: It should be in the BIOS.

Comment: +1, though strictly speaking the memory remapping should only affect PAE and other 32bit configurations. AFAIK it wouldn't affect an x64 system.

Comment: Memory remapping affects an x64 system. If the memory isn't remapped, the OS can't access it.

Comment: That setting is in the BIOS, on boot push delete when asked then go to Advanced>Uncore Configuration>Memory Remap Feature. Unfourtunately that image is exactly what mine looks like including the "4GB To 3328MB" and the "Enabled" parts even though I have 8GB.

Comment: Hmm, that doesn't seem to be the regular memory remapping feature. That seems to be something different. Your BIOS may be different from the ones that I'm used to. For grins, try disabling it.

Comment: When disabled Windows 7x64 states "3.31 GB useable" VS "4 GB useable" when enabled. While starting up it states there are 3328MB instead of 4096MB. It does exactly what it says... for once.

Comment: Sadly, then, this isn't the setting you're looking for. Check the BIOS for any other memory-related settings. Are you sure all four sticks are properly inserted?