# 3,44GB of RAM available of 8GB (now 12GB after RAM replacement)

Tags: memory, graphics-card, bios, windows-11

My computer came with 8GB of RAM, but at some point half of the ram seemed to stop working. The system still detects it but marks it as hardware reserved. I have integrated graphics, but they only account for about 512MB.

I have already tried the following: Reinstalling Windows, updating BIOS, replacing the ram stick, unchecking maximum memory, resetting CMOS, tried most permutations of virtual memory settings, and running memory diagnostic which found no issues.

The new RAM stick I installed, which should by all accounts be compatible, has 8GB instead of the previous ones 4, however this has only resulted in the computer reporting 3,44GB available of 12 rather than 3,44 available of 8. There is no apparent physical damage to the RAM slot itself, and the problem occurred without me touching the installed RAM at all. Around the time it occurred I did update my graphics driver, though this may be after the problem happened as I updated it to fix problems that I now think were caused by the faulty memory.

I have tried every suggested fix for this kind of issue with no luck. Do I assume my motherboard is faulty? This is on Windows 11.

Comment: What models are your computer and the RAM stick(s)?

Comment: Your memory was just fine, Hardware Reserved is a function of the firmware, your motherboard isn’t faulty. We will need more information. [Here](https://superuser.com/questions/405579/installed-memory-ram-8gb-4gb-useable?rq=1) is like one of about 20 explanations for the behavior you describe

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Installed Memory (RAM): 8GB (4GB Useable)](https://superuser.com/questions/405579/installed-memory-ram-8gb-4gb-useable)